# How do I compare matching variables in two dataframes and pull data from a 3rd column where cases match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I've been wracking my head with this and cannot find an answer on stackoverflow. Im trying to match two identifier columns in both dataframes and pulling the results from a column within my 2nd dataframe and fill an empty column in my 1st dataframe

DF1:

| Name | Code | Has_Power |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | A1 | NaN |
| Mike | B2 | Nan |
| Mary | C3 | Nan |
| Bill | D4 | Nan |
| Anne | E5 | NaN |

DF2:

| Code | Has_Power |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | True |
| B2 | False |
| E5 | True |

Expected Output:

| Name | Code | Has_Power |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | A1 | True |
| Mike | B2 | False |
| Mary | C3 | Nan |
| Bill | D4 | Nan |
| Anne | E5 | True |

My code doesnt seem to work

```
   df1['Has_Power'] df1.merge(df2, left_on=['Code', 'Has_Power'], right_on=['Code', 'Has_Power'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1.Has_Power = df1.Code.map(dict(df2.values))
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
   Name Code Has_Power
0  John   A1      True
1  Mike   B2     False
2  Mary   C3       NaN
3  Bill   D4       NaN
4  Anne   E5      True
```

Idea is to create a `mapping dict` from `2nd dataframe` and use that dict to fetch the required values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1.drop('Has_Power', axis=1).merge(df2, on=['Code'], how='left')
```